# How to join my table with information_schema.columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to join my table with information_schema.columns to get data type for all column.

my sql is following.

```
select stock_code,automatic,semiautomatic,manual from VehicleInfoForParts
```

i want to join my VehicleInfoForParts with information_schema.columns to get a output like

```
Column_Name       Value               datatype
-------------     -------            --------------             
stock_code           A112                varchar
automatic            1                   bit
semiautomatic        0                   bit
manual               1                   bit
```

please advise. thanks .

Comment: You're asking to change columns into rows. It would be easier to have extra columns like "stock_code_datatype" and "automatic_datatype" etc. Would this be OK?

Comment: Why you want to do that? If you just use the query you quote `select xxx from Vehiclexxx`, describing the result columns will get you the data type... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is an answer to your question via T-SQL:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067562/t-sql-how-to-count-of-records-for-each-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve that with a simple join (you basically want to "join" columns with rows...). As I said in your earlier question, solve your problem with the bit columns in the application, not in the database. That has multiple advantages, including

- It works for every table holding bit columns if you keep your data model consistent
- You don't store language specific texts in your SQL code, with makes translating your application easier

Comment: +0 - This doesn't really address his question at all.